# Trying to use selenium to webscrape ncbi, the data doesn't load and isn't contained in an element with an ID that I can wait for

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape genetic data from web pages like https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov//nuccore/KC208619.1?report=fasta.

I am using beautiful soup and selenium.

The data is located inside an element with the id viewercontent1.
When I print that out with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import re

secondDriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/me/Documents/chloroPlastGenScrape/chromedriver')

newLink = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov//nuccore/KC208619.1?report=fasta"
secondDriver.implicitly_wait(10)
WebDriverWait(secondDriver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
secondDriver.get(newLink)
html2 = secondDriver.page_source
subSoup = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')
viewercontent1 = subSoup.findAll("div", {"id" : "viewercontent1"})[0]
print(viewercontent1)
```

I print out :

```
<div class="seq gbff" id="viewercontent1" sequencesize="450826" style="display: block;" val="426261815" virtualsequence=""><div class="loading">Loading ... <img alt="record loading animation" src="/core/extjs/ext-2.1/resources/images/default/grid/loading.gif"/></div></div>
```

It seems the content hasn't finished loading.
I tried implicitly waiting and checking to see if the content is done loading (before and after calling the .get() function) but that doesn't seem like it did anything.
I can't wait for the content to load specifically via ID (presence_of_element_located) because the data is contained directly within a `<pre></pre>` element with on id.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get content of the `<div>`, you can use this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov//nuccore/KC208619.1?report=fasta'
fasta_url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id={id}&report=fasta'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
id_ = soup.select_one('meta[name="ncbi_uidlist"]')['content']
fasta_txt = requests.get(fasta_url.format(id=id_)).text

print(fasta_txt)
```

Prints:

```
>KC208619.1 Butomus umbellatus mitochondrion, complete genome
CCGCCTCTCCCCCCCCCCCCCCGCTCCGTTGTTGAAGCGGGCCCCCCCCATACTCATGAATCTGCATTCC
CAACCAAGGAGTTGTCTCATATAGACAGAGTTGGGCCCCCGTGTTCTGAGATCTTTTTCAACTTGATTAA
TAAAGAGGATTTCTCGGCCGTCTTTTTCGGCTAGGCTCCATTCGGGGTGGGTGTCCAGCTCGTCCCGCTT
CTCGTTAAAGAAATCGATAAAGGCTTCTTCGGGGGTGTAGGCGGCATTTTCCCCCAAGTGGGGATGTCGA
GAAAGCACTTCTTGAAAACGAGAATAAGCTGCGTGCTTACGTTCCCGGATTTGGAGATCCCGGTTTTCGA

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you, very elegant. Now I will do my best to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrej's solution seems much simpler but if you still want to go the waiting route...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

newLink = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov//nuccore/KC208619.1?report=fasta"
driver.get(newLink)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#viewercontent1 pre"))
    )

html2 = driver.page_source
subSoup = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')
viewercontent1 = subSoup.findAll("div", {"id" : "viewercontent1"})[0]
print(viewercontent1)
```